# expo-location watchHeadingAsync not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I use expo-location (12.0.4) to watch the heading of the device to align a compass. On IOS all works fine but on Android the heading changes without moving the device. Following you can find my code:

```
followHeading = async () => {
  this.HeadingListener = await Location.watchHeadingAsync(this.headingChanged);
};

headingChanged = async(heading) => {
  if(this._isMounted){
    Animated.timing(this.heading, {
      toValue: Math.round(-heading.trueHeading),
      duration: 7,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }
};
```

I logged the changes of watchHeading:

```
 LOG  trueHeading: 265.4945373535156
 LOG  trueHeading: 267.6138916015625
 LOG  trueHeading: 265.55670166015625
 LOG  trueHeading: 267.6473693847656
 LOG  trueHeading: 265.5852355957031
```

So the trueHeading changes about two degrees without moving the device. I also tried to use the magHeading with the same result.

Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

Comment: I also tried to use react-native-device-heading with the same result. I think this is a React Native issue. I use React Native 0.64.2